# Forcing a build success even after test-failures in order to continue a build pipeline

Tags: shell, gradle, build.gradle, sh, junit5

I have a series of JUnit 5 tests which must run in batches (Using tags). Once a batch finishes, the next batch should continue. If any tests fails in the first batch, the second batch **does not start** and this is not the behaviour I would like.

I've been told to use Gradle or Shell to return exit code zero (which is a success) so the batch of tests continue in a pipeline. I understand the implications of this - that the build will always show as passed.

---

In my build.gradle file I have tried:

```
test {
    ignoreFailures = true

    useJUnitPlatform {
        includeTags  itags
        excludeTags  etags
    }
    testLogging {
        events("passed", "skipped", "failed")
    }
    afterSuite {
        if (test.result == TestResult.FAILURE) {
            System.exit(0)
        }
    }
}
```

The afterSuite throws an error so I'm not sure I have the syntax error. The build doesn't recognise the "test."

I have also tried in Shell

```
set +x
gradle clean build test
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  exit 0
fi
set -x
```

Which does not work either.

Comment: what's the error? copy and paste here please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below you can find a complete example project that hopefully does what you’re after (tested with Gradle 8.0.2). The project uses the [JVM Test Suite Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.2/userguide/jvm_test_suite_plugin.html) to define one test suite for each batch of tests with a certain JUnit 5 tag.

### Files in the Example Project

We have the following directory structure (not showing [Gradle Wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.2/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) files for brevity):

```
├── build.gradle
├── settings.gradle
└── src
    └── test
        └── java
            └── org
                └── example
                    └── MyTest.java
```

`settings.gradle` is empty and `build.gradle` has the following content:

```groovy
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

testing {
    suites {
        configureEach {
            useJUnitJupiter('5.9.2')
            sources {
                java {
                    // Override the default which is based on the suite name.
                    srcDirs = ['src/test/java']
                }
            }
            targets {
                all {
                    testTask.configure {
                        ignoreFailures = true
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // The "test" suite is provided by default. Let's use it for the first
        // batch tagged with "my-tag1".
        test {
            targets {
                all {
                    testTask.configure {
                        options {
                            includeTags 'my-tag1'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // The "test2" suite is created here. We use it for the second batch of
        // tests that are tagged with "my-tag2".
        test2(JvmTestSuite) {
            targets {
                all {
                    testTask.configure {
                        options {
                            includeTags 'my-tag2'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

tasks.named('check').configure {
    dependsOn(testing.suites.names)
}
```

Here’s the content of `MyTest.java`:

```java
package org.example;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Tag;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.fail;

public class MyTest {

    @Tag("my-tag1")
    @Test
    public void myTest1() {
        fail("test 1 fails");
    }

    @Tag("my-tag2")
    @Test
    public void myTest2() {
        fail("test 2 fails");
    }
}
```

Note that there are failing tests for all of our tags.

### Running the Example Project

We can either run the batches individually using `./gradlew test` and `./gradlew test2`, or we can run them all in one go with `./gradlew check`. For the latter, we get the following output:

```
> Task :test

MyTest > myTest1() FAILED
    org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError at MyTest.java:13

1 test completed, 1 failed
There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///path/to/my_proj/build/reports/tests/test/index.html

> Task :test2

MyTest > myTest2() FAILED
    org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError at MyTest.java:19

1 test completed, 1 failed
There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///path/to/my_proj/build/reports/tests/test2/index.html

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
4 actionable tasks: 4 executed
```

Despite the failing tests in each batch, the overall build is marked as successful (because of the used `ignoreFailures = true` configuration). The exit code of the overall build is hence also 0.